# Appropriate implementation of packet stream using standards

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing a driver for a serial device that communicates in the form of discrete packets.  I'd also like the user to be able to interpret packets from a dump file of serial traffic.  I plan to write other, similar drivers in the future.

After looking through available libraries and the standard, I was thinking of implementing std::codecvt, which is used by iostream to convert to wide characters, to provide a way to convert between a stream of bytes and a stream of packet objects, and handling asio such that the serial port may be a standard stream of bytes.

This seemed the most elegant approach to me, that made the most use of standards, but I am worried it is a misuse of codecvt.  Reading the docs for codecvt it is clearly intended to convert character encodings only.  But it appears it would work fine with higher level packet objects.

It is enticing to use the familiar insertion and extraction operators to deal with higher level data, and this approach means minimal boilerplate code is needed to accomplish that.

Is this idea a misuse of codecvt?  What is the "correct" or "best" solution here in your experienced opinion?

Answer (score 0):

We pair up Asio and Boost.Spirit to convert streams of bytes in to data types and data types into streams of bytes.

We use it so often that we have abstracted the concept into a generic packetizer library that can take a Qi/Karma grammar and an Asio type that can be used with `async_read_some`.

We use this with serial ports, TCP/IP sockets, and customized IO.